# Storybook 6 - ReactJS and Typescript : refers to a value, but is being used as a type here (TS2749)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am trying to import a class dynamically into a React component like so:

```
foo.tsx
export class Foo { 
   doFoo() {
      // ....
   }
}
```

```
foo-page.tsx
import { Foo } from "../foo";
export interface FooPageProps {
  foo: Foo;
}
export const FooPage = (props: FooProps): JSX.Element => {
  props.foo.doFoo()
}
```

Running `yarn webpack-dev-server --mode development --progress --color` everything seems to compile but running `yarn start-storybook -p 6007 -s public` it throws this error.

Any thoughts? Been trying to debug the issue for a while but I've gathered that basically while in storybook, it appears to be importing the JS value but not the type for some reason but while running the webpack dev server it appears to be importing both so this error doesn't appear.

Comment: Where is your story declared?

Comment: It's in a foo-page.stories.tsx file in the same directory as foo-page.tsx.

Comment: I found the issue...it was a caching problem of a previously generated JS file (foo.js generated for foo.tsx) that was sitting in the same directory. I believe webpack was resolving the correct TSX file but storybook was linking to the old compiled JS file until I deleted it.